# Registration page. Printing out user errors in php

Tags: php, html, registration

I've created a registration page whch checks for errors and prints them out for the user. For example if they do not have a valid email address it says invalid email address. At the top where the logic is done it lets the webpage know if there are any errors so later I can register them without errors. In the bottom where the html it I am trying to printout errors so they show next to the text field. I have created some errors but for some reason they print before the user even prints anything. The code is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
                    <?php if(@$_POST['action'] == 'register') {
                    }
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Firstname"/>
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Lastname"/><br /><br />
                    <input type="text" name="username" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Username" />
                    <?php if(user_exists($_POST['username']) === true){
                            echo "Username already exsits.";
                            }else if(preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true){
                            echo 'Your username must not contain spaces.';
                            }
                    ?>
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="password" name="re_password" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" />

                            if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['re_password']){
                            echo "Your passwords do not match.";
                            }else if(strlen($_POST['password']) !== 0 && strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
                            echo "Your password must be at least 6 characters.";
                            } 
                    ?>
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength = "25" class="text-bars" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input type="text" name="re_email" maxlength = "25" class="text-bars" placeholder="Re-enter Email" />
                    <?php
                        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false && $_POST['email'] !== 0){
                            echo "A valid email address is required.";
                        }else if(email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
                            echo "Email address already in use.";
                        } else if($_POST['email'] !== $_POST['re_email']){
                            echo "Your emails do not match.";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="text" name="zipcode" maxlength = "7" class="text-bars" placeholder="Zip Code" /><br /><br />

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
```

The errors that checks for a password is above 6 characters long and email validate seem to print right when the page loads. Any solutions to this problem?

Thanks everyone!

```
$errors = array();

if(empty($_POST) === false){
$required_fields = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'username', 'password', 're_password', 'email', 're_email', 'zipcode');
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true){
        $errors[] = 'All fields are required';
        break 1;
    }
}

if(empty($errors) === true){
    if(user_exists($_POST['username']) === true){
        $errors[] = 'Username already exsits.';
        }
    if(preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true){
        $errors[] = 'Your username must not contain spaces.';
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters.';
    }
    if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['re_password']){
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords do not match.';
                            }
    if(strlen($_POST['password']) !== 0 && strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters.';
                            }
    if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $errors[]= 'A valid email address is required.';
    }
    if(email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
        $errors[] = 'Email address already in use.';
    } 
    if($_POST['email'] !== $_POST['re_email']){
        $errors[] = 'Your emails do not match.';
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to see if they have submitted the form before checking for errors. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Thank you! Im unfamiliar with that function and do not understand how I would use that to set it was not completed though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an input hidden to your code inside the `<form>` element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
```

Around your php code, use the following

```
<?php if(@$_POST['action'] == 'register') {

} ?>
```

This will trigger your php code only when the form is submitted by the user.

This is the exact code you need

```
<?php
    if(@$_POST['action'] == 'register') {
        if(user_exists($_POST['username']) === true){
            $errorUser = "Username already exsits.";
        }else if(preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true){
            $errorUser = 'Your username must not contain spaces.';
        }

        if($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['re_password']){
            $errorPassword = "Your passwords do not match.";
        }else if(strlen($_POST['password']) !== 0 && strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
            $errorPassword = "Your password must be at least 6 characters.";
        }

        if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false && $_POST['email'] !== 0){
            $errorEmail = "A valid email address is required.";
        }else if(email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
            $errorEmail = "Email address already in use.";
        } else if($_POST['email'] !== $_POST['re_email']){
            $errorEmail = "Your emails do not match.";
        }
    }
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />
    <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Firstname"/>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Lastname"/>
    <?=@$errorUser;?>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="username" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Username" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="re_password" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" />
    <?=@$errorPassword;?>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" maxlength = "25" class="text-bars" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" name="re_email" maxlength = "25" class="text-bars" placeholder="Re-enter Email" />
    <?@$errorEmail;?>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" maxlength = "7" class="text-bars" placeholder="Zip Code" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I added to the code above in the password part. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Move my code to the top of the page, and put all the error codes inside it. No need to have them at the bottom of the page. And that should work.

Comment: Yes. But you need to move all your other errors into the same if. And, remove the : after `<?php if(@$_POST['action'] == 'register'): {` ): all the way at the end there.

Comment: So I move all the errors I have after the different input fields into there and remove them without? If so how would I print each error in the correct spot?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the validation gets done whether or not the form has been submitted. I would recommend doing all of your validation in PHP before your html, you can use an array to capture errors and print them out in the form. This will keep your logic and content separated to a greater degree which makes debugging easier.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) { //Check that the form has actually been submitted
    $errors = array();
    if(user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
        $errors['user'] == 'Username exists';
    }
    ... // more error checking
}

... //form output
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength = "16" class="text-bars" placeholder="Username" />
<?php print(isset($errors['username'])) ? $errors['username'] : ''; ?>
... //more form output
```

That should get you started

Comment: I added that part in the above section

Answer (score 0):

First, declare errors

```
$errors = array();
```

Everytime you catch an error, append it to the variable

```
$errors[] = 'Your Error Text';
```

Finally, print the errors

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($errors as $error) {
    echo "<li>$error</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: So I could use the second code I added above to do this and then use the print errors part you just suggested to print in the html part?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you validate user input in a separate block of code after submit, e.g. at the top of your script:

```
if (isset($_POST("submit")) {  // form has ben submitted...

    // validate
    if (!isset($_POST['firstname']) || strlen($_POST['firstname']) == 0)
        $error['firstname'] = "Please enter a first name!";

    // do this with all your fields

    if (!isset($error)) { // no error = all fields valid

        // save fields to database
        // route to another page
        exit();
    } // if !isset $error

} // if isset
```

in your form, you...

```
<form name="myform" method="post">
<?php=(isset($error)?'There were errors:':'')?>
<?php $fieldname = 'firstname'; ?>
<?php=(isset($error[$fieldname])?$error[$fieldname].'<br />':'')?>
<input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="16" 
    class="text-bars<?php=(isset($error[$fieldname])?' error':'')?>" 
    value="<?php=(isset($_POST[$fieldname])?$_POST[$fieldname]:'')?>"/>

<!-- do the same for all other fields... -->

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> <!-- add name attribute! -->
</form>
```

Like this, you are displaying an error-message...
  - on top of the form if `$error` is set
  - on top of the field that contains an error if `$error[fieldname]` is set...
  - the `class` attribute of the field is set to `text-bars error`, so if you define a class error, you can highlight the field.